# Cocoa button opens a System Preference page

Tags: cocoa, macos, preferences

In a OSX Cocoa app, I would like a button that would open the "speech" preference pane. Is that possible? I'm just trying to save them the time to go System Preferences > Speech > Text to Speech

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The following is a fairly easy (and reliable) way to at least get System Preferences open to the Speech.prefPane:

```
- (IBAction)openSpeechPrefs:(id)sender {
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:
     [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/System/Library/PreferencePanes/Speech.prefPane"]];
}
```

However, it won't necessarily be switched to the `Text to Speech` tab, but rather the last tab the user had selected.

It is possible to actually switch to the Text to Speech tab as well, but it's a bit more involved. You can use AppleScript to send commands to the System Preferences application, but using the `ScriptingBridge.framework` (See [Scripting Bridge Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html)) is much faster.

You'll need to add the `ScriptingBridge.framework` to your project, and then use a command like the following in Terminal to generate a `SBSystemPreferences.h` header file to work with:

`sdef "/Applications/System Preferences.app" | sdp -fh --basename SBSystemPreferences -o ~/Desktop/SBSystemPreferences.h`

Add that `SBSystemPreferences.h` header to your project, then change `-openSpeechPrefs:` to the following:

```
- (IBAction)openSpeechPrefs:(id)sender {
    SBSystemPreferencesApplication *systemPrefs = 
    [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.systempreferences"];

    [systemPrefs activate];

    SBElementArray *panes = [systemPrefs panes];
    SBSystemPreferencesPane *speechPane = nil;

    for (SBSystemPreferencesPane *pane in panes) {
        if ([[pane id] isEqualToString:@"com.apple.preference.speech"]) {
            speechPane = pane;
            break;
        }
    }
    [systemPrefs setCurrentPane:speechPane];

    SBElementArray *anchors = [speechPane anchors];

    for (SBSystemPreferencesAnchor *anchor in anchors) {
        if ([anchor.name isEqualToString:@"TTS"]) {
            [anchor reveal];
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Sample project using the ScriptingBridge.framework method:
http://github.com/NSGod/OpenSystemPrefsTTS

Comment: I typed the `sdef` command in terminal, got the following error and warning:    `sdp: error: class "pane" inherits from undefined class "item".
sdp: error: class "anchor" inherits from undefined class "item".` So I cannot get the header file.

Comment: @NSGod Mavericks. And I found that you would get the header though there were errors and warnings.

Comment: This method does not work for sandboxed apps. Atleast in yosemite

Comment: For Yosemite you would just do something like: **x-apple.systempreferences://Speech**

Answer (score 48):

One can even select specific sub item inside a pref pane.
Here is example to select Camera under Privacy pane:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Camera"];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:URL];
```

Some credit goes to following site: https://macosxautomation.com/system-prefs-links.html

List of URLs for reference (*updated for macOS Big Sur & Catalina & Mojave):

```
Accessibility Preference Pane
Main    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess
Display x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Seeing_Display
Zoom    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Seeing_Zoom
VoiceOver   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Seeing_VoiceOver
Descriptions    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Media_Descriptions
Captions    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Captioning
Audio   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Hearing
Keyboard    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Keyboard
Mouse & Trackpad    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Mouse
Switch Control  x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Switch
Dictation   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?SpeakableItems

Security & Privacy Preference Pane
Main    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security
General x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?General
FileVault   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?FDE
Firewall    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Firewall
Advanced    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Advanced
Privacy x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy
Privacy-Camera x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Camera
Privacy-Microphone  x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Microphone
Privacy-Automation  x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Automation
Privacy-AllFiles    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_AllFiles
Privacy-Accessibility   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Accessibility
Privacy-Assistive   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Assistive
Privacy-Location Services   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_LocationServices
Privacy-SystemServices  x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_SystemServices
Privacy-Advertising x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Advertising
Privacy-Contacts    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Contacts
Privacy-Diagnostics & Usage x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Diagnostics
Privacy-Calendars   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Calendars
Privacy-Reminders   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Reminders
Privacy-Facebook    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Facebook
Privacy-LinkedIn    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_LinkedIn
Privacy-Twitter x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Twitter
Privacy-Weibo   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Weibo
Privacy-Tencent Weibo   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_TencentWeibo

macOS Catalina 10.15:
Privacy-ScreenCapture   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_ScreenCapture
Privacy-DevTools    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_DevTools
Privacy-InputMonitoring x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_ListenEvent
Privacy-DesktopFolder   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_DesktopFolder
Privacy-DocumentsFolder x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_DocumentsFolder
Privacy-DownloadsFolder x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_DownloadsFolder
Privacy-NetworkVolume   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_NetworkVolume
Privacy-RemovableVolume x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_RemovableVolume
Privacy-SpeechRecognition   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_SpeechRecognition

macOS Big Sur 10.11/10.16:
Privacy-Bluetooth   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Bluetooth
Privacy-Music   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Media
Privacy-Home    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_HomeKit

macOS Monterey 12.0:
Privacy-DoNotDisturb    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Focus

macOS Ventura 13.0:
Privacy-AppBundles    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_AppBundles
Privacy-ListenEvent    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_ListenEvent


Dictation & Speech Preference Pane
Dictation   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.speech?Dictation
Text to Speech  x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.speech?TTS
Sharing Preference Pane
Main    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing
Screen Sharing  x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_ScreenSharing
File Sharing    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_PersonalFileSharing
Printer Sharing x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_PrinterSharing
Remote Login    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_RemoteLogin
Remote Management   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_ARDService
Remote Apple Events x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_RemoteAppleEvent
Internet Sharing    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Internet
Bluetooth Sharing   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_BluetoothSharing

Software update x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate?client=softwareupdateapp
```

All this is possible thanks to key in Info.plist in preferencePane + CFBundleURLTypes (CFBundleURLSchemes) x-apple.systempreferences (Info.plist) in System Preferences.app

> NSPrefPaneAllowsXAppleSystemPreferencesURLScheme

As of 10.15 some of the keys are located in PrivacyTCCServices.plist (Security.prefPane)

As of 10.14 Mojave some Privacy keys ceased to exists. Mojave privacy list:[image]

Catalina privacy list:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to open Software Update panel to the "Automatic updates" info button (i) in macOS Ventura as well by any chance? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @marek-h is this allowed in the AppStore? If not is there an approved way?

Comment: @user1046037 Yes all is approved and widely used

Comment: @MarekH Where from did you got this information? Is there exist information about Sonoma?

Comment: @Andrew_STOP_RU_WAR_IN_UA This was in 2018 by reverse engineering. Steps are included. macOS has changed since so internally Ventura/Sonoma is different as they use new system preferences

Answer (score 0):

For the guys who run into the same issue that I mentioned in the comment, just go to the `~/Desktop` (cos I specify this position) and you'll see the `SBSystemPreferences.h` has been created.

However, in this header, some class declarations are missing. So you have to add this declarations explicitly.

In my case, class "item" is undefined. So add this:
`@class SBSystemPreferencesItem;`

Then compile it and see what's still missing, which declaration needs to be added.