# How to generate a header file for Reminders.app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, scripting-bridge

I’m a bit familiar with Scripting Bridge, and have used it for controlling the play/pause/back/next functions in iTunes. Through `sdef` and `sdp` I was able to create an iTunes.h file, with which I could declare an `iTunesApplication` object.

When I tried to do the same thing for the inbuilt Reminders.app I got an error that said

> sdp: error: class "list" inherits from undefined class "item”.
>
> sdp: error: class "reminder" inherits from undefined class "item”.

Could any one help me in creating a Reminders.h file?

Comment: Check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19649354/913522) on a almost-same problem as you.

Hope that helps.