# How to launch system preferences to a specific preference pane using bundle identifier?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, bundle-identifier, nsworkspace

I'm trying to open the system date & time preferences directly from my app. 
I can seem to open System Preferences with no issue using:

```
let settingsBundleIdentifier = "com.apple.systempreferences"

NSWorkspace.shared.launchApplication(withBundleIdentifier: settingsBundleIdentifier, options: [], additionalEventParamDescriptor: nil, launchIdentifier: nil)
```

But I can't figure out how to go directly to the date & time pane.

I tried changing the bundle identifier to `com.apple.systempreferences:com.apple.datetimepref` and `com.apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.datetime` to no avail.

What should I be doing here?  Can one not open the pane directly through the bundle identifier?

I'm aware that I can open the preference pane directly using file path to `DateTime.prefPane`. But I'm looking to open it using bundle identifiers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cocoa button opens a System Preference page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652598/cocoa-button-opens-a-system-preference-page)

Comment: @Willeke I can see that I can open it using file path as stated in the answer above. But was looking to see if I can open it directly with just the bundle identifier?

Answer (score 30):

## 2023:

Any needed Preference Panes(.prefPane):

```
NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(fileURLWithPath: "/System/Library/PreferencePanes/%PrefsNsme%.prefPane"))
```

replace `%PrefsNsme%` to any needed filename that is located at:

```
/System/Library/PreferencePanes/
```

---

systemPrefs:

```
NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(string: "x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference")!)
```

---

Some of the System Preferences are actually grouped as extensions, and called using this format:

```
NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(string: "x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.%ExtensionName%)!)
```

Extension list curated from:

```
/System/Applications/SystemSettings.app/Contents/Resources/Sidebar.plist
```

List of Extension URLs for reference [macOS Ventura]. Some use .extension some do not:

```
Family Settings: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Family-Settings.extension
Software Update: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.FollowUpSettings.FollowUpSettingsExtension
Wifi: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.wifi-settings-extension
Bluetooth: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.BluetoothSettings
Network: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Network-Settings.extension
Classroom Settings: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.ClassroomSettings
Classroom Settings2: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Classroom-Settings.extension
Notifications: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Notifications-Settings.extension
Sound: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Sound-Settings.extension
Focus: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Focus-Settings.extension
Screen Time: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Screen-Time-Settings.extension
Appearance: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Appearance-Settings.extension
Accessibility: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Accessibility-Settings.extension
Control Center: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.ControlCenter-Settings.extension
Siri: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Siri-Settings.extension
Spotlight: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Spotlight-Settings.extension
Privacy Security: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.settings.PrivacySecurity.extension
Desktop: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Desktop-Settings.extension
Displays: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Displays-Settings.extension
Wallpaper: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Wallpaper-Settings.extension
Screen Saver: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.ScreenSaver-Settings.extension
Battery: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Battery-Settings.extension
Lock Screen: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Lock-Screen-Settings.extension
Touch ID: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Touch-ID-Settings.extension
Users Groups: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Users-Groups-Settings.extension
Passwords: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Passwords-Settings.extension
Passwords2: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Passwords
Internet Accounts: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Internet-Accounts-Settings.extension
Game Center: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Game-Center-Settings.extension
Wallet: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.WalletSettingsExtension
Keyboard: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Keyboard-Settings.extension
Mouse: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Mouse-Settings.extension
Trackpad: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Trackpad-Settings.extension
Game Controller: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Game-Controller-Settings.extension
CD-DVD: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.CD-DVD-Settings.extension
Print Scan: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Print-Scan-Settings.extension
```

---

List of URLs for reference [updated for macOS Ventura]:

```
Accessibility Preference Pane
Main    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess
Display x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Seeing_Display
Zoom    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Seeing_Zoom
VoiceOver   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Seeing_VoiceOver
Descriptions    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Media_Descriptions
Captions    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Captioning
Audio   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Hearing
Keyboard    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Keyboard
Mouse & Trackpad    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Mouse
Switch Control  x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Switch
Dictation   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?SpeakableItems

Security & Privacy Preference Pane
Main    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security
General x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?General
FileVault   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?FDE
Firewall    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Firewall
Advanced    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Advanced
Privacy x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy
Privacy-Camera x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Camera
Privacy-Microphone  x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Microphone
Privacy-Automation  x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Automation
Privacy-AllFiles    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_AllFiles
Privacy-Accessibility   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Accessibility
Privacy-Assistive   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Assistive
Privacy-Location Services   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_LocationServices
Privacy-SystemServices  x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_SystemServices
Privacy-Advertising x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Advertising
Privacy-Contacts    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Contacts
Privacy-Diagnostics & Usage x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Diagnostics
Privacy-Calendars   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Calendars
Privacy-Reminders   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Reminders
Privacy-Facebook    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Facebook
Privacy-LinkedIn    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_LinkedIn
Privacy-Twitter x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Twitter
Privacy-Weibo   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Weibo
Privacy-Tencent Weibo   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_TencentWeibo

macOS Catalina 10.15:
Privacy-ScreenCapture   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_ScreenCapture
Privacy-DevTools    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_DevTools
Privacy-InputMonitoring x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_ListenEvent
Privacy-DesktopFolder   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_DesktopFolder
Privacy-DocumentsFolder x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_DocumentsFolder
Privacy-DownloadsFolder x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_DownloadsFolder
Privacy-NetworkVolume   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_NetworkVolume
Privacy-RemovableVolume x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_RemovableVolume
Privacy-SpeechRecognition   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_SpeechRecognition
Privacy-DevTools    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_DevTools

macOS Big Sur 10.11/10.16:
Privacy-Bluetooth   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Bluetooth
Privacy-Music   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Media
Privacy-Home    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_HomeKit


Dictation & Speech Preference Pane
Dictation   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.speech?Dictation
Text to Speech  x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.speech?TTS
Sharing Preference Pane
Main    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing
Screen Sharing  x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_ScreenSharing
File Sharing    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_PersonalFileSharing
Printer Sharing x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_PrinterSharing
Remote Login    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_RemoteLogin
Remote Management   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_ARDService
Remote Apple Events x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_RemoteAppleEvent
Internet Sharing    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Internet
Bluetooth Sharing   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_BluetoothSharing

Software update x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate?client=softwareupdateapp

macOS Monterey 12.0:
Privacy-DoNotDisturb    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Focus

macOS Ventura 13.0:
Privacy-AppBundles    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_AppBundles
Privacy-ListenEvent    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_ListenEvent

Dictation & Speech Preference Pane
Dictation   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.speech?Dictation
Text to Speech  x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.speech?TTS
Sharing Preference Pane
Main    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing
Screen Sharing  x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_ScreenSharing
File Sharing    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_PersonalFileSharing
Printer Sharing x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_PrinterSharing
Remote Login    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_RemoteLogin
Remote Management   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_ARDService
Remote Apple Events x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_RemoteAppleEvent
Internet Sharing    x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Internet
Bluetooth Sharing   x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.sharing?Services_BluetoothSharing

Software update x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate?client=softwareupdateapp

//https://stackoverflow.com/a/48139877/4423545
```

More useful information about topic:
https://github.com/bvanpeski/SystemPreferences/blob/main/macos_preferencepanes-Monterey.md

## UPD:

## Sonoma changed preference system so this may now work on Sonoma. Please doublecheck!

Comment: `import AppKit` ;)

Comment: is there a way to dump the additional parameters? for example, how do i figure out additional parameters for the newly added Extensions.prefPane?

Comment: @Casey you need to find the same list for monterey and to find needed string :) If you will find it -- please update my answer with it :)

Comment: Is it allowed to use such keys? From my readings, these are Apple's private keys which the apps are not allowed to use.

Comment: @espc yep, it's just an URLs that is accessible from OS.

Answer (score 6):

I found the following code to open the Security PrefPane to a certain page:

```
    let prefpaneUrl = URL(string: "x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Accessibility")!
    NSWorkspace.shared.open(prefpaneUrl)
```

but oddly, when I try the same for Date & Time

```
    let prefpaneUrl = URL(string: "x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.datetime"
    NSWorkspace.shared.open(prefpaneUrl)
```

it doesn't work, nor if I use the bundle identifier of the Date & Time PrefPane:

```
    let prefpaneUrl = URL(string: "x-apple.systempreferences:system.preferences.datetime")!
    NSWorkspace.shared.open(prefpaneUrl)
```

**Update:** There is a list of working pref pane identifiers here: http://web.archive.org/web/20190606022433/https://macosxautomation.com/system-prefs-links.html
Seems Date & Time just isn't exposed.

Comment: Dang, bluetooth is not exposed :/ thanks for the link though!

Comment: @AlexPera I reverted your edit. Please do not just change links in answers to different sites. It makes it look like a site was endorsed by the original poster. If a link goes dead, either replace it with a web archive link, or leave a comment with your different, working link.