# How do I read Security & Privacy/Automation settings programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm updating a Mac OS application that relies on other apps. Specifically, the user selects an action and each action has a corresponding application assigned to it (like Terminal). When I initially install the application and the user selects a given action, the OS will prompt the user for action saying that my application is looking to control another application and that settings need to be updated for that to be allowed.

Is there any way to read these settings from my application to explicitly check whether each of the applications I expect to control is being allowed or blocked?

I know I can open the corresponding preferences dialog using something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53617674/419639 but I would like to avoid doing that every time a user runs my application, so I'd prefer to check Automation settings myself prior to displaying the dialog.

Comment: You can read TCC database. https://rainforest.engineering/2021-02-09-macos-tcc/.