# Is there any way I can ask for the Accessibility permission for MacOS in flutter?

Tags: flutter, macos, permissions, accessibility

I am working on flutter where I need to ask user to go to preferences and allow accessibility permission for MaxOS. is there any way I can ask for it in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter you can not do it out of the box. You need to write platform channels and native code for that.

Accessibility topic is something that is limited by the Apple to prevent security issues. A lot of different approaches were out there and working but since El Capitan all of them are deprecated.

---

Nevertheless you still can write your own custom code with your own dialog window and make it. You can check the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/1460720-axisprocesstrusted?language=objc) for the native platform and check this [answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53617674/1744873)

Comment: But now flutter do not allow to write native methods for macOS

Comment: It does, I did it before on my project here --> https://github.com/salihgueler/desktop_window_utils. If your app has macos support, you need to write the native code there and call that function from Dart.