# Flutter Desktop: Read and Replace Input Value in Any Application

Tags: flutter

I have a requirement to develop an application like Grammarly Desktop, where they are able to read any input text and suggest corrections that can be replaced in the input area too... They are able to do it in any application, like any browser, slack, notes, Docs, etc; (It's important to specify that I'm not referring to the Grammarly browser extension, the Desktop app is the only one able to do it in any application).

[Grammarly desktop extension in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBupu.png)
[Grammarly desktop extension in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FbQ1.png)

The application that I need to develop is only for macOS and I have almost sure that they make use of the Accessibility resources of MacOS to be able to make these behaviors (read the input text of any application and the possibility to switch them). Me and my team are flutter developers and we would like very much to use flutter in order to build our application, but we don't found any solution for makes use of this Accessibility and read/write any input texts **using Flutter**...

Before we give up using flutter for this and go to a native language, does anyone know something that can solve this case and make using flutter possible?

I've found this related question: [Is there any way I can ask for the Accessibility permission for MacOS in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71202956/is-there-any-way-i-can-ask-for-the-accessibility-permission-for-macos-in-flutter)

But it's an older reply and maybe now with the recent updates, it can be done.

Comment: I'm quite curious about this too. Did you manage to find out?
Thanks!

Comment: Not using flutter :( I used swift to do it

Comment: And if I may ask, did you do it via the use of accessibility features or is there a different way you took with swift?

Comment: Exactly, I used the Accessibility API. I think there is no other way...