# Is there an equivalent of openSettingsURLString in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, uikit, swiftui, uialertaction

I want to create an alert that redirects the user to Settings App after they denied camera usage for the first time, but the only way that I've seen so far uses UIKit and

```
let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default, handler: {action in
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    })
```

In SwiftUI, there is an actions option within alert, how would I be able to correctly open settings through SwiftUI's version of alert?

```
.alert(isPresented: $alertVisible) { () -> Alert in Alert (title: Text("Camera access required to take photos"), message: Text("Go to Settings?"), 
     primaryButton: .default(Text("Settings"), action: UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)), 
     secondaryButton: .default(Text("Cancel"))
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here it is

```
.alert(isPresented: $alertVisible) {
     Alert (title: Text("Camera access required to take photos"),
            message: Text("Go to Settings?"),
            primaryButton: .default(Text("Settings"), action: {
                UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!)
            }),
            secondaryButton: .default(Text("Cancel")))
        }
```

Comment: Your solution works fine on iOS, but on Mac with Catalyst I don't see the system preferences window: how can I fix?

Comment: This needs to be used in DispatchQueue.main.async { // here }, or Xcode will show a warning

Answer (score 14):

In shortest form you can use something like this:

```swift
Link("Open settings ?", destination: URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!)
```

This will create you a simple looking button that will lead directly to the Settings app. Of course, you can customize the look further using view modifiers.

---

Alternatively if you need more control, you can use `openURL` `@Environment` property wrapper in your view, like so:

```swift
struct SomeView: View {
    @Environment(\.openURL) var openURL

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: openSettings) {
            Label("Open settings?", systemImage: "gear")
        }
    }

    private func openSettings() {
        openURL(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution (see answer @rmaddy at [link][1]):

```
.alert(isPresented: $showLibraryPicker, content: {
            Alert(title: Text("Camera access required to take photos"),
                  message: Text("Go to Settings?"),
                  primaryButton: .default(Text("Settings"),
                                          action: {
                                            let url: String
                                            #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
                                            url = "x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Photos"
                                            #else
                                            url = UIApplication.openSettingsURLString
                                            #endif
                                            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: url)!)
                                          }), secondaryButton: .default(Text("Cancel")))
        })


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58330598/is-there-a-way-to-send-the-user-to-the-apps-privacy-settings-under-macos-like-w
```